# Why "await" always need to be used in an "async" function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I always wondered at first what does await does and with experience i slowly started to understand why but after some after i started testing an api that needed to be awaited (mathjs), i had a question. **Why does "await" always need an "async" ?**

I mean why can't we use await alone for example whenever javascript see this

```js
const result = await justa.functiOn()
```

it will read it like this :

```js
async function t(){
const result = await justa.functiOn()
}
t()
```

That would be useful, save time and errors.

**I don't need an answer to fix an error i have** but just to understand more javascript because i've been searching in many websites but nothing did help me understand.. They only repeated that await needed 'async' ;-;

And i know i can just us an async function englobing everything together. Again i am not trying to solve a problem/erro but i still am very curious about why we can't use await alone without async.

Comment: The async keyword creates a special function that runs outside the main thread and can pause and resume. Using await requires such a function. The latest node versions allow using await at the top level, since blocking the main thread is not as bad as inside a browser environment.

Comment: @Chris `async` functions do *not* "run outside the main thread". They still run on the same thread as anything else. The async call they `await` might then be running on a different, lower-level background thread.

Comment: Purely syntactically, `await` _could_ be made to work without `async`. But logically, an `await`ed value will only be available *sometime later*, and that "infects" everything up the call chain (i.e. the caller will have to `await`, and *its* caller will have to, and so on). So, it does make sense to mark those functions specifically, even beyond other implementation detail advantages that might bring.

Comment: @deceze thanks, I didn't know that. Now I do, which is great!

Comment: Specifically for your example: Because then `result` would not be available immediately on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

**Why does "await" always need an "async" ?**

This is because if you were able to put await in synchronous code, you would block the (main) thread.

This was already possible to do before `async` and `await` keywords.

You can simply [resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) a promise. An async function returns such a promise.

Comment: It doesn't really answer why the async can't then be implicitly inferred from using await, no?

Comment: I mean technically it's possible to add that to the javascript specification. There's a reason why they didn't.